# JSON REST API Wordpress only showing first 10 categories

Tags: php, categories, rest-api, json

Alphabetically ordered categories are shown first (first 10). If I try to show all categories in JSON / Wordpress, it's not showing it.

So, imagine these are the categories:

```
A
B
C
D
E
F
G
H
I
J
K (=10)
L = not shown anymore
```

How can I make sure I fetch them all?

I am trying to fetch them in Dart via JSON, so I can only pass that to Dart. Is there a way I can achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is normal behaviour, you've not accounted for pagination. The REST API returns 10 results per page by default, and can be configured to return up to but no more than 100 per page.

You may be tempted to try `-1`, but this will not work, 100 is the maximum results per page that can be requested for performance and scaling reasons.

WordPress provides 2 http headers indicating the total number of pages, and the total number of results across all pages so that you know how many requests are needed to fetch all results.

I ***strongly*** recommend reading the REST API handbook in the official documentation. [This page covers how to use and control pagination, sorting, etc.](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/pagination/)

Comment: Alright, but is there a way to make sure that it's not on alphabetical order? And there is no other way to show more than 10?

Comment: @Johan You can set `order` and `orderby` ([see docu](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/categories/#arguments)). As for fetching all, just do multiple requests - until you have reached the last page.

Comment: @Johan that's literally the next section of the doc I linked you to, I wasn't joking when I said you should read it, I was being deadly serious, read the entire doc, both your questions are answered there in full complete with how to get the pages, how to sort and order them